# How to stop PHP script after it executes for 3 mins

Tags: php

My website is hosted on digitalocean server and i have full control over the server. I have php script that downloads thousand of images using proxy IP. Sometimes my script takes infinite time and it slows the whole site. I checked max_execution_time and it is set to default 30 secs. But still my script doesn't stop after 30 secs. How can i stop my script from running after 2 mins so that my site doesn't effect other scripts.

Comment: try recording the timestamp at the beginning and referencing it each iteration

Answer (score 0):

The max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations, database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum time that the script has been running.

refer this [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#75557) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try recording the timestamp at the beginning and referencing it each iteration. Use `break;` or `return;` to exit the loop

```
function getImagesFromRemote($urlArray=[]) {
  $start = time();
  $maxduration = 3 * 60 ;
  foreach ($urlArray as $url) {
     // do your code
    $something[] = $value;
    $elapsed = time() - $start;
    if ($elapsed >= $maxduration) break;
  }
  return $something;
}

}
```

Comment: @farazch - Did this help solve your question? If so, please accept as the answer. thanks

Answer (score -1):

By using exit() function we can stop the execution of php script. The exit() function only terminates the execution of the script. The shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit() function is called.

Comment: this doesn't address the question - OP is asking how to not exceed a certain time